# Google Analytic not updated in iOS Cordova 2.0.0 App

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, google-analytics

I am working on iOS App using Cordova 2.0.0, and I want to use Google Analytics, So I followed this github link step by step, but Unfortunately GA not updated, The only difference that 
in the link Readme file "Make sure you are running Cordova(PhoneGap) 1.5.0" 
and I use Cordova 2.0.0
but I see that the repo is updated to 2.0.0 and my App is work right but GA not updated

and here it is the code that I call in OnDeviceReady method, to start the GA and add event

```
var googleAnalytics = window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin;
googleAnalytics.startTrackerWithAccountID("XX-XXXXXXXX-X");
googleAnalytics.trackEvent("category", "action", "label goes here", 666);
```

Can any one help or face the same problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? Does the google analytics plugin actually make it into the page? eg, does ```console.log(window.plugins)``` spit out an entry for GA?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly the follow the below link,its very helpful and also worked for me.
 ----> **https://github.com/jelled/google-analytics-cordova-ios**

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Hi Kleopatra, Thanks for your suggestion,actually the steps are too lengthy and its quite clearly mentioned there and if Mohamed face any difficulty am there to help him

Comment: @Saikat actually I worked on Cordova 2.0, but I attend to update it, So whenever I update it, I will try this plugin and tell you about the results.

Comment: Hi Mohamed , you dont need to update,it will work with Cordova 2.0.0,I had used Cordova 2.5.0 so please try this out and mark my suggestion as answer